# Which of the operator overloads in C++ have mandatory parameter data types?

Tags: c++

Consider the ++ operator in C++:

```
struct number {
    int a = 0;
};

number operator++(number num) {
    return {num.a + 1};
}

number operator++(number num, int dummy) {
    return {num.a + 1};
}
```

Depending on whether the prefix or postfix ++ operator is desired, you need to add a dummy parameter of type int.

What I'm wondering about is whether any other operators exist in C++ which have either mandatory parameter types, or mandatory return types? For instance, as far as I can tell there's nothing preventing me from defining an == operator which returns a value of type `number`, which breaks the language convention of always returning `bool`, but does appear to compile.

Comment: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Note that none of the increment operators you implement are implemented the expected way: none modify the object passed (which they can't, since you pass by value instead of by reference) and the preincrement operator doesn't return a reference. This already messes up expectations.

Comment: The general "rule" is that operators shouldn't break the common semantics of operators. And your increment operators *do* break the semantics, since they don't actually increment `num` (and in fact won't build since you haven't declared an `operator+` overload for the `number` structure).

Comment: You can define them (mostly) however you want, up to and surpassing the point of much cursing from anyone other than yourself that dares venture into the abyss of the resulting code malaise. Do note, however, that the operators still carry precedence according to their traditional implementations against their native upbringing.

Comment: Only the postfix increment and decrement operators have a mandatory parameter type, which in these cases is a *dummy* parameter.  The operator *acting* on a type requires that type to be specified.  The *return* type can be anything.  There are idiomatic expectations, but those are not required by the language.